# How to add event on click on ant design vue table column title?

Tags: vue.js, antd

```
const columns = [
  { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', width: 300 
    onHeaderCell: column => {
      return {
        onClick: e => {
          this.customize(e);
        },
      };
    },},
  { title: 'Employee ID', dataIndex: 'displayId', width: 150 },
  { title: 'Normal', dataIndex: 'normal.name', width: 100 },
  { title: 'Overtime', dataIndex: 'overtime.name', width: 100 },
  { title: 'Holiday', dataIndex: 'holiday.name', width: 100 },
  { title: 'Rest Day', dataIndex: 'restDay.name', width: 100 },
];
```

I have an ant design vue table and want to add event on click to change the title name. But I can't add on click event and customize the column title.

Is there any way to make this happen when click the column title will triggered a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using this [Ant Design Vue](https://antdv.com/docs/vue/introduce/) and this [Table](https://antdv.com/components/table/) component.

You can use custom title by specify `column.slots.title`:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    slots: {
      title: 'customTitle'
    }
  }
]
```

And define your `customTitle` slot:

```html
<span slot='customTitle'>
  <div @click='editTitle'>{{ title }}</div>
</span>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/j4g9b7re/)

Comment: i've tried before but there's nothing changed in the title

Comment: it's work on your js fiddle. but not in my code. i've try this 
       `<span slot='customTitle'>
          test change
        </span>`
and this 
`{
    title: 'Name',
    slots: {
      title: 'customTitle'
    },
    dataIndex: 'name',
    width: 150,
    fixed: 'left',
    headerCell: "customs",
    slots: {
      title: 'customTitle'
    }`

but still there's nothing happen

Comment: owh i got it.. it's due to i have not remove the column title. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter for each item for example "isClickable" and put a click listener on each item of the v-for which will enter in a method that check if the item is clickable or not.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div
            v-for="column in columns"
            @click="clickOnColumn(column)"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        columns: [
            {
                title: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                width: 300,
                isClickable: true,
            },
            { title: 'Employee ID', dataIndex: 'displayId', width: 150 },
            { title: 'Normal', dataIndex: 'normal.name', width: 100 },
            { title: 'Overtime', dataIndex: 'overtime.name', width: 100 },
            { title: 'Holiday', dataIndex: 'holiday.name', width: 100 },
            { title: 'Rest Day', dataIndex: 'restDay.name', width: 100 },
        ],
    }),

    methods: {
        clickOnColumn(column) {
            if (column.isClickable) {
                // Execute code
            } else {
                return null
            }
        },
    },

}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```